# Merging algorithm to sort two string arrays while merging

Tags: c, string, algorithm, merge

I have made a program with two string arrays. List 1 & List 2. they are unsorted.

The program runs and the two lists are individually sorted using a bubble sort algorithm. Then they are merged together into a third array and printed out to the screen.

At this stage I have tried to get the merging to sort the arrays together while merging them with little success. To merge the first half and second half together so its both lists alphabetically sorted together using merge sort. Currently, the merging only adds the arrays together. This algorithm i hopefully use for bigger arrays. Any advice would be amazing!Sorry for poor English, not my first language!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BIG 42
int main()
{
//initialising variables and the arrays containing each of the four groups.
char *list1 [10] = 
{ 
    "Ant ", 
    "Donald ", 
    "Mark ", 
    "Paul ", 
    "Steven ", 
    "Andrew ", 
    "Kenneth", 
    "George ", 
    "Joshua ", 
    "Kevin " 
} ;

char *list2 [6] = 
{   
    "Frank ", 
    "Brandon ", 
    "Greg ", 
    "Samuel ", 
    "Patrick ", 
    "Alexander "
} ;

int length_list1 = 10 ;
int length_list2 = 6 ;
char *big_array2 [BIG] ;  

//This is a bubble sorting Algorithm. It sorts list1 & list2 in order and then prints the sorted arrays out.
//
for (int j = 0 ; j < length_list1 - 1 ; j++ )//This loop takes the top number off every time the algorithm repeats to save time,
{
    for (int i = j + 1 ; i < length_list1 ; i++ ) //this loop goes from 0 to the length of list1 and will do everything within the braces.
    {
        if( strcmp( list1[j],  list1[i]) > 0 ) //strcmp is a function that compares the strings to see which is alphabetically closer to a.
        {
            char *temp =  list1[j] ;//temp stores one of the strings if a swap needs to be done.
            list1[j] =  list1[i] ;
            list1[i] = temp ;
        }//end if
    }//end for
}//end for

for (int j = 0 ; j < length_list2 - 1 ; j++ )//This loop takes the top number off every time the algorithm repeats to save time,
{
    for (int i = j + 1 ; i < length_list2 ; i++ )//this loop goes from 0 to the length of list2 and will do everything within the braces.
    {
        if( strcmp(list2[j],list2[i]) > 0 ) //strcmp is a function that compares the strings to see which is alphabetically closer to a.
        {
            char *temp = list2[j] ;//temp stores one of the strings if a swap needs to be done.
            list2[j] = list2[i] ;
            list2[i] = temp ;
        }//end if
    }//end for
}//end for

//Printing the sorted arrays out using for loops.
//
printf( "\n\nlist1(in order) :\n " ) ;
for ( int i = 0 ; i < length_list1 ; i++ )
printf( "\n%d) %s", i + 1, list1[i] ) ;
printf( "\n\nlist2(in order) :\n " ) ;
for ( int i = 0 ; i < length_list2 ; i++ )
printf( "\n%d) %s", i + 1, list2[i] ) ;
//This is a merging algorithm. It merges list1 &list2 into the array big_array2.
//
//intiailising variables that will be used for while loops.
//
int i = 0 ;
int j = 0 ;
int index = 0 ;

while( i < length_list1 && j < length_list2 ) //This while loop will continue while i is less than the length of the first array
{                                               //and j is less than the length of the second array.
    if( strcmp( list1[i], list2[j] ) > 0 ) //This if statement uses the strcmp function and compares the n elements of the two arrays.
    {                                        //If list1 is alphabetically closer to 'a' then it will be added to n spot of the big array.
        big_array2[index] = list1[i] ;
        i++ ;                               //Now 'i' will be incremented by one so in that array it moves on to the next number for comparison.
    }//end if

    else                                    //If list2 is alphabetically closer to 'a' then it will be added to n spot of the big array.
    {
        big_array2[index] = list2[j] ;
        j++ ;                               //Now 'j' will be incremented by one so in that array it moves on to the next number for comparison.
    }//end else
    index++ ;                               //Now 'index' will be incremented by one so the big arrays position will increase by one so another comparison between
}//end while                                                                    // the two arrays can be done.

while( i < length_list1 )                  //This is a while statement incase that j reaches its length before i. then it will assume that i has to take the rest of the spots in the big array.
{
    big_array2[index] = list1[i] ;
    i++ ;
    index++ ;
}//end while

while( j < length_list2 )                  //This is a while statement incase that i reaches its length before j. then it will assume that j has to take the rest of the spots in the big array.
{
    big_array2[index] = list2[j] ;
    j++ ;
    index++ ;
}//end while
printf( "\n\n\n" ) ;
puts("");
for ( int index=0; index < 16; index++)
{
    printf("Merged %d is %s\n", index+1, big_array2[index]);
}
getchar();
return 0;
 }//end main()
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
  list1(in order) :

  1) Andrew
  2) Ant
  3) Donald
  4) George
  5) Joshua
  6) Kenneth
  7) Kevin
  8) Mark
  9) Paul
  10) Steven

   list2(in order) :

   1) Alexander
   2) Brandon
   3) Frank
   4) Greg
   5) Patrick
   6) Samuel



   Merged 1 is Andrew
   Merged 2 is Ant
   Merged 3 is Donald
   Merged 4 is George
   Merged 5 is Joshua
   Merged 6 is Kenneth
   Merged 7 is Kevin
   Merged 8 is Mark
   Merged 9 is Paul
   Merged 10 is Steven
   Merged 11 is Alexander
   Merged 12 is Brandon
   Merged 13 is Frank
   Merged 14 is Greg
   Merged 15 is Patrick
   Merged 16 is Samuel
```

Comment: Use function, because your code is a big stack of line, and it's difficult to see at first glance where the problem occure. Make an ArraySorting function, an ArrayDisplay function, that will clean a little your main. Finally, if your objectif is just to have a final array sorted, you can just "merge" the two array in one, and then "sort" the result array. it's the simpliest way, thougth it's not as efficient as doing a merge sort like you inted to do.

Comment: try `if( strcmp( list1[i], list2[j] ) < 0 )` - you are currently using the *greater* of the two strings in your merge.

Comment: Obligatory: "the two lists are individually sorted using a bubble sort algorithm." - don't ever use bubblesort.

Comment: i need efficent merge sort. I will do function too.

Comment: for portable, <s>efficient</s>decent sorting, look into `qsort`

Comment: efficient depending on the situation ! There are no "efficient" sorting algorithm for every situation. qsort happen to be a relative good choice for most of case, but clearly saying "efficient" may be misleading since it heavily depend on the data you are trying to sort.

Comment: "efficient" as in "likely to be more efficient than anything you can roll yourself in an hour" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was correct, but the issue was in the if condition

```
if( strcmp( list1[i], list2[j] ) > 0 )
```

The sign should be `<` instead of `>`

Try this code line instead of the previous one and it will work.
You are trying to find the string with lower to higher and what you are trying to say in if condition is  find the higher one. Because of that, first if condition doesn't give you the desired results.

```
if( strcmp( list1[i], list2[j] ) < 0 )
```